# GWT getElementbyId to equivalent widget / Panel

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to build a dynamic web app in GWT, when widgets are added to the screen I remember their 'name' by setting the Widget.setId, when I want to replace part of the page, I can find the element in question via DOM.getElementById('name'), and its parent using DOM.getParentElement(), and then remove its children.

Now I have a com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element object (the parent).  What I want to do is turn this back into a GWT object - in fact it'll be something derived from Panel, so I can add additional Widgets.

How do I go from the Element object back to a Panel object ?

I totally accept I could be going about this the wrong way, in which case is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach to remove widgets from the DOM using *DOM.getElementById('name')* is not the proper one.

On your case (I am just figuring out what you do), I would keep Java Objects references instead of accessing to them using the DOM.

For instance:

```
HorizontalPanel panel = new HorizontalPanel();
Widget w = new Widget();
//We add the one widget to the panel
panel.add(w);
//One more widget added
w = new Widget();
panel.add(w);
//Now we remove all the widgets from the panel
for(int i = 0; i < panel.getWidgetCount(); i++){
    panel.remove(panel.getWidget(i));
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments, I would propose the following solution.
I suppose that you are storing widgets on *HorizontalPanel*, just apply this solution to your concrete case.
I propose to use customized class which inherits from *HorizontalPanel* and add a *Map* there to store relationship between names and widgets.

```
public class MyHorizontalPanel extends HorizontalPanel {

    private Map<String, Widget> widgetsMap;

    public MyHorizontalPanel(){
        super();
        widgetsMap = new HashMap<String, Widget>();
    }

    //We use Map to store the relationship between widget and name
    public void aadWidget(Widget w, String name){
        this.add(w);
        widgetsMap.put(name, w);
    }

    //When we want to delete and just have the name, we can search the key on the map.
    //It is important to remove all references to the widget (panel and map)
    public void removeWidget(String name){
        this.remove(widgetsMap.get(name));
        widgetsMap.remove(name);
    }

}
```

Comment: This had been my first approach, but I need to be able to find (then remove and replace) a particular panel by name, so I started storing the names against the panels in a ArrayList.  But this seems to lead to a massive memory leak - when deleted they remain in the DOM (unattached) I believe (I'm no expert) that the Garbage Collector will not remove them as it still thinks there's a reference to them (even after removed from the list), so I moved to the approach here

Comment: Updated based on your comments. Check if ti fits please ;-)